# React JS: Component not being shown with custom route component?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to create protected routes in my react application. If I go to a protected route, and do not get redirected, I am given a blank screen and the component doesn't get shown / rendered ?

If its this, the component isn't displayed:

```
<ProtectedRoute exact path="/home" component={Home} />
```

If its this, it does get displayed:

```
<Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
```

Protected route:

```
import auth from '../utilities/auth';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProtectedRoute({ component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => {
      return auth.isAuthenticated()
        ? component
        : <Redirect to='/accounts/login' />
    }} />
  )
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox to reproduce this? the question why it does not display anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually render the component. Right now you're just returning the component but not rendering it. By just returning `component` you're doing the equivalent of returning `Home`, whereas what you should be doing is returning `<Home />`.

What you should be doing is something like

```
// assigning component to Component so React knows it's a custom component when you render it
function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={() => {
      return auth.isAuthenticated()
        ? <Component /> // so you're actually rendering the component
        : <Redirect to='/accounts/login' />
    }} />
  )
}
```